# docker-compose: MongoDB connection refused

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I'm new to Docker and am trying to get an existing project set up in a container. The project is a Node app (running through Keystone JS) that depends on MongoDB.

My `docker-compose.yml` file contains:

```
version: "2"

services:

  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - /data/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    command: mongod --bind_ip_all

web:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  links:
    - mongodb
  environment:
    - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongodb/site
```

The app attempts to connect to the database using the `MONGO_URL` environment variable but I get the following error:

```
web_1      | Mongoose connection "error" event fired with:
web_1      | { MongoError: failed to connect to server [mongodb:27017] on first connect [MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongodb mongodb:27017]
web_1      |     at Pool.<anonymous> (/opt/mainsite/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:327:35)
web_1      |     at Pool.emit (events.js:160:13)
web_1      |     at Connection.<anonymous> (/opt/mainsite/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:274:12)
web_1      |     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:255:19)
web_1      |     at Connection.emit (events.js:160:13)
web_1      |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/opt/mainsite/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:177:49)
web_1      |     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:255:19)
web_1      |     at Socket.emit (events.js:160:13)
web_1      |     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
web_1      |     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19)
web_1      |   name: 'MongoError',
web_1      |   message: 'failed to connect to server [mongodb:27017] on first connect [MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongodb mongodb:27017]' }
web_1      | Error: KeystoneJS (site) failed to start - Check that you are running `mongod` in a separate process.
web_1      |     at NativeConnection.<anonymous> (/opt/mainsite/node_modules/keystone/lib/core/openDatabaseConnection.js:59:10)
web_1      |     at NativeConnection.emit (events.js:160:13)
web_1      |     at Immediate.<anonymous> (/opt/mainsite/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:317:19)
web_1      |     at runCallback (timers.js:756:18)
web_1      |     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:717:5)
web_1      |     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:697:5)
web_1      | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
web_1      | npm ERR! errno 1
web_1      | npm ERR! new_site@0.0.0 start: `node keystone`
web_1      | npm ERR! Exit status 1
web_1      | npm ERR! 
web_1      | npm ERR! Failed at the new_site@0.0.0 start script.
web_1      | npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
web_1      | 
web_1      | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
web_1      | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-02-03T22_47_26_963Z-debug.log
new_web_1 exited with code 1
```

The `ENOTFOUND` return makes it seem like somethings wrong with the network bridge between the containers but nothing I've found online can fix this issue.

Comment: For **docker-compose** mongo service is up *when this starts the container*, but inside them mongodb is still starting up (the port 27017 is not available yet and could take some seconds). I fixed my code using a mongoose (my ODM) connection retry. My fix is commented here:
https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/1255#issuecomment-384470189

Answer (score -1):

Following are some checks you may perform:

- Is hostname `mongodb` is resolvable from the docker from which you're running your app? You can use `telnet` to verify that
- Is mongodb is running inside mongodb docker?
- Is mongodb is bound to listen only on localhost interface?